# Making string column consistent/clean in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm working with a dataset that has "unclean" string columns. These are company names, and most of these were entered in manually, so there are typos and different forms of representation. The dataset column looks something like this:

```
company_name
big compnay
big company
big company inc.
smll compny
small company
small inc.
```

I am trying to edit the above column to something like below:

```
company_name
big company
big company
big company
small company
small company
small company
```

The number of datapoints is much larger than what can be cleaned manually. I would really appreciate any suggestions/help/advice. I've tried working with modules such as `fuzzywuzzy`, but I couldn't figure out the best way to deal with the problem above.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think pandas has a built in function to deal with it. May be you can try creating a function for a character map, or a distance vector method (which takes in to account order of letters and letters itself) to deal with it

Comment: What is the objective of this exercise? Can you show a sample mapping from "dirty" to "clean" data?

Comment: @JijoJose Right, I'm grappling with that at the moment. It's something I've never done...

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I just edited the question to reflect the mapping from "dirty" to "clean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a probabilistic spell corrector to correct words with one or two edit distances from a word with much higher frequency of occurrence in your dataset. A Python implementation is provided here: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: Hmm... Thanks! I'll try this

Comment: This seems to require a "corpus" of "correct" words. In my case, this would require a "correct" list of company names. This is doable, but would take several days for me to manually go through them to get a "correct" list of company names. Then I can probably do something like `get_closest_matches`.

Comment: One way to avoid manual selection is by assigning a probability score for each value based on the number of occurrences in your dataset. For example, I expect Probability['smll compny'] < Probability['small company']. Next, you re-pass through the whole list and transform ones with lower occurrences to a word with higher probability and at a 1-edit, 2-edit, ..., n-edit distance.

Comment: That's interesting. It sounds like a very good idea. I was thinking about purchasing a list of all U.S. companies, but I will try this! Thanks so much!

Comment: I recently implemented this in R for my own side project. You can check out the code here: https://github.com/sharan-naribole/H1B_visa_eda/blob/master/spell_correcter.R
If it works, please upvote and mark as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I already upvoted, but due to my low reputation, my upvote isn't displayed publicly (although it says that it's accounted for). Thanks!